# Sms Not sending on real device in android application but it is perfectly working on emulator

Tags: android, sms

It's working on emulator but not working on real device, why? Please help me ... thanks in advance!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, Text, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Comment: Got credit/SIM/signal? :-P

Comment: i added scaddress also .... bt not working ... trapping in Sending Report that  SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE

Comment: I cant getting you Sir , King Cronus :)

Comment: Post the complete code. Also your logs

Comment: Not working => Then include some codes and logcat output if any.